# Alfresco document library - Adding sub menus to 'create'

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I've created a custom alfresco model which has 52 types of custom objects which I want to appear in the 'create' menu drop down.  52 options looks a bit cluttered, so I was hoping I could organise them into sub menus of the create.

E.g.

```
Create
    > Type A
        > Object Type 1
        > Object Type 2
    > Type B
        > Object Type 3
        > Object Type 4
```

Right now my configuration looks something like this:

```
<config condition="DocumentLibrary" evaluator="string-compare">
    <create-content>
        <content icon="object-type-1" id="plain-text" itemid="ancoat:objectType1" label="Object Type 1" mimetype="text/plain"/>
        <content icon="object-type-2" id="plain-text" itemid="ancoat:objectType2" label="Object Type 2" mimetype="text/plain"/>
        <content icon="object-type-3" id="plain-text" itemid="ancoat:objectType3" label="Object Type 3" mimetype="text/plain"/>
        <content icon="object-type-4" id="plain-text" itemid="ancoat:objectType4" label="Object Type 4" mimetype="text/plain"/>
    </create-content>
</config>
```

Is there an option to select which sub menu each content option should appear on?

Comment: By looking at the share-configuration, I don't think, you can use sub-types directly. I tried with sub-folder for Node Templates and it is not working also.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via share-config, as far as I know, but you can rewrite toolbar.js, which is responsible for rendering the menu. See this link for an example:

https://heshawa.wordpress.com/alfresco-create-from-template-menu-arrange-with-sub-menues/